# How to add custom datas on symfony validators

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I am working with Symfony constraint validators

I wrote custom validator class and throw violation if needed like this:

```
$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('bettingslip')
                ->addViolation();
```

Output gave me expected message:

> [
>     {
>       "property_path": "bettingslip",
>       "message": "bettingslip.message"
>     }
>   ]

But I need some extra datas in output (like error details, etc.) for some development.
What I would like on output:

> [
>     {
>       "property_path": "bettingslip",
>       "message": "bettingslip.message",
>       "data": {"var1": "value1"}
>     }
>   ]

I dont know how I can add this "data" properly when I throw violation in validator. I had a look on Symfony Class, but nothing on this way.